# How to get the same variables from two different classes and write ones to another by json, changing class?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm new in Jackson framework.

I have two classes First and Second, they don't have common superclass.

In method convertOneToAnother first argument is "first" object, and second argument is Second class, this class object we have return from this method.

```
public static Object convertOneToAnother(Object one, Class resultClassObject) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    mapper.writeValue(writer, one);

    String json = writer.toString();

    return mapper.readValue(json, resultClassObject);
}
```

This two classes have the same variables:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  property="className")
@JsonSubTypes(@JsonSubTypes.Type(value=First.class,  name="first"))
public static class First {
    public int i;
    public String name;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  property="className")
@JsonSubTypes(@JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Second.class, name="second"))
public static class Second {
    public int i;
    public String name;
}
```

When I comment json adnotations above classes declarations it's working but if not I have exception:

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'first' as a subtype of `com.codegym.task.task33.task3304.Solution$Second`: known type ids = [second]

How I can handle this problem in  convertOneToAnother method? Maybe is some way to tell compiler "I know what I'm doing, ignore that names is invalid" or "change the name="first" to name="second"?

Comment: I found solution -> mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);